# Word encompassing all transformations of a word (conjugation, plurization, etc.)

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a singular word or phrase which encompasses all of the many types of transformations you may perform on a word, such as conjugation, pluralization, nominalization, adjectivization, etc.?

The best I've come up with so far is "transformations," but that is a very generic word. Having a word that is more precise would be great.

I would have thought I'd have been able to find the word by hunting around with those keywords, but I had no such luck.

Comment: The technical word in linguistics is *paradigm*. The paradigm of a word includes all its possible inflections. The term *declension* is mostly used to refer to groups of nouns or adjectives that decline in the same way, or alternatively the act of declining them. The paradigm of *be* consists of the forms *am, is, are, was, were, being, been* and *be*. The paradigm of the word *big * consists of the forms *big, bigger, biggest*. You can’t really use the word *declension* in the same way.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I think paradigm is actually bigger than the word I was looking for. However, I believe *inflection* is the word I was after. I'm looking for the word that would fit this sentence: "[In written form] Style the word like this, regardless of <insert word here>".

Comment: Yes, inflection seems like the word your after :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably looking for ***[declension](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declension):***

> In linguistics, declension is the changing of the form of a word, generally to express its syntactic function in the sentence, by way of some inflection.

> Declensions may apply to nouns, pronouns, adjectives, adverbs, and articles to indicate number (e.g. singular, dual, plural), case (e.g. nominative case, accusative case, genitive case, dative case), gender (e.g. masculine, neuter, feminine), and a number of other grammatical categories.

(Wikipedia)

Comment: "Yes, but..." I've always had the vague impression that "declension" applied (technically speaking, only) to non-verbs in the same way that "conjugation" applied (only) to verbs. Is there a term for the Venn-diagram-union of declension and conjugation? and/or is my vague impression incorrect? (FWIW, I agree that if you said "decline a verb," people would _understand_ the intended meaning, even if it turned out to be _technically_ a misuse of the term.)

Comment: I agree with @Quuxplusone; the proper umbrella term is *inflection*.

Comment: @jwodder: That sounds like you should post it as an answer!

Comment: @jwodder: As the OP, I agree. It does look like *inflection* is the more appropriate term, encompassing both declension and conjugation.